# TypeScript does not determine the type even if it has all necessary information

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I came across this issue in TypeScript types. I'm using a conditional type based on a different property in the same interface to determine the type of one property. Here, the property `slicer` in `FruitBasket` is either `AppleSlicer` or `BananaSlicer` depending on the `type`.

If you look at the function `test`, it receives a instance of `FruitBasket`, which can be either `Apple` or `Banana`. So, I narrow down the type by checking that the `type` is equal to one of them, but it still complains that `basket.slicer` is not deterministic. But, it should have all information it needs to determine that it's an `AppleSlicer`.How can I fix this?

I'm using TypeScript 4.5.4.

```js
enum Fruits {
  Apple = "Apple",
  Banana = "Banana",
}

// These interfaces can have completely different shapes as shown.
interface AppleSlicer { apple(): void }
interface BananaSlicer { banana(): void }

export type FruitSlicer<TType> = TType extends typeof Fruits.Apple
  ? AppleSlicer
  : TType extends typeof Fruits.Banana
  ? BananaSlicer
  : never

export interface FruitBasket<TType extends Fruits> {
  type: TType
  slicer: FruitSlicer<TType>
}

const test = (basket: FruitBasket<Fruits>) => {
  if (basket.type === Fruits.Apple) {
   // This gives me a compile error because basket.slicer is either AppleSlicer or BananaSlicer.
   // But, it should have all information it needs to deduce that it can only be an AppleSlicer
    basket.slicer.apple()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big problem here is that `FruitBasket<Fruits>` is not a proper [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where you can check a discriminant property (which would be `type`) to narrow the type of the object.  Not only isn't it a discriminated union, it's not even a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) at all.  It's equivalent to

```
{ type: Fruits, slicer: AppleSlicer | BananaSlicer }
```

So here is a completely valid `FruitBasket<Fruits>` according to that definition:

```
const whoops: FruitBasket<Fruits> = {
  type: Fruits.Apple,
  slicer: { banana() { } }
} // okay
```

Just because `type` is `Fruits.Apple`, it doesn't mean that `slicer` will be a `FruitSlicer<Fruits.Apple>`.  So if `test()` accepts a `FruitBasket<Fruits>`, then it accepts `whoops`:

```
test(whoops) // no error here either
```

And *that* means the implementation of `test()` really cannot safely conclude anything in particular about `basket.slicer` by looking at `basket.type`.  The compiler error is a valid one.  Whoops.

---

So you don't want `test` to accept `FruitBasket<Fruits>`.  What you want is the union type `FruitBasket<Fruits.Apple> | FruitBasket<Fruts.Banana>`, a discriminated union where `type` is the discriminant property.

If you don't want to write that type out manually (e.g., there are lots of other `Fruits` in your `enum`), you can generate this union from your version of `FruitBasket<T>` as follows:

```
type FruitBasketUnion = { [F in Fruits]: FruitBasket<F> }[Fruits]
// type FruitBasketUnion = FruitBasket<Fruits.Apple> | FruitBasket<Fruits.Banana>
```

Here we are creating a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with a `FruitBasket<F>` property type for each `F` in `Fruits`, and then immediately [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that mapped type with `Fruits` to get the desired union.

Now we can make that the parameter type for `test()` and see that the check `basket.type === Fruits.Apple` *does* narrow the type of `basket` to `FruitBasket<Fruits.Apple>`:

```
const test = (basket: FruitBasketUnion) => {
  if (basket.type === Fruits.Apple) {
    basket.slicer.apple() // okay
  }
}
```

Now the `test()` implementation compiles with no error.  That had better mean you can't call `test(whoops)` anymore:

```
test(whoops); // error!
//   ~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'FruitBasket<Fruits>' is not assignable to
// parameter of type 'FruitBasketUnion'.
```

So the compiler correctly rejects `whoops`.  Let's make sure it accepts `FruitBasket<Fruits.Apple>` and `FruitBasket<Fruits.Banana>`:

```
test({
  type: Fruits.Banana,
  slicer: { banana() { } }
}); // okay

test({
  type: Fruits.Apple,
  slicer: { apple() { } }
}); // okay
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFwM5QN4CgpQIIAOBANsFALxQBEhJwVANDlAEICGIHbF17nnjLAF8sWAPRioAFQAWwVGUQhkwOADM2AY3lRNHKDLYA3MpoD2EOiuIBPKABNEatatDIoqQwR1t0nswDuIAB0WEoq6lpktKQAysSI2nCYUGxEpAAUAJQAXFBGZoj2UCLhqhrarFyc8YmqKQBG1WzZeQVFJaLAAB4EZnDuyDbesAgotUkAPFJSw8AAfDwzc1A9KiD26EPeZmqjSGjBMcDMAPz46cATqsx5yyNroJtQ28C7+yiowXxcZ1X8bGucFuUBAwBMwKwPT6AygZUilXgB3YqAA1sBkNNZg9uutnkjPotsLhXndsSdcKgEkk8gTkECsXN5sJRGIAFRYOko9GYumoRaIdDyBTKRBsYi2FKkj5oBgeamqPLHIFQAA+-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)

Comment: It’s a great answer. 

Answer (score 1):

My preferred pattern would be to adapt the slicers to a common pattern, where you wouldn't have to do such a check. (I'll update in a few minutes) The answer to your question, though, is to have an explicit typeguard to check the type properly, and this would return confirmation to the type system that it indeed matches your conditions for being a specific type.

```
enum Fruits {
  Apple = "Apple",
  Banana = "Banana",
}

// These interfaces can have completely different shapes as shown.
interface AppleSlicer { apple(): void }
interface BananaSlicer { banana(): void }

export type FruitSlicer<TType> = TType extends typeof Fruits.Apple
  ? AppleSlicer
  : TType extends typeof Fruits.Banana
  ? BananaSlicer
  : never

export interface FruitBasket<TType extends Fruits> {
  type: TType
  slicer: FruitSlicer<TType>
}

const test = (basket: FruitBasket<Fruits>) => {
  if (isAppleBasket(basket)) {
   // This gives me a compile error because basket.slicer is either AppleSlicer or BananaSlicer.
   // But, it should have all information it needs to deduce that it can only be an AppleSlicer
    basket.slicer.apple()
  }
  else if (isBananaBasket(basket)) {
    basket.slicer.banana()
  }
}

function isAppleBasket(candidate: FruitBasket<Fruits>): candidate is FruitBasket<Fruits.Apple> {
    return candidate.type === Fruits.Apple;
}
function isBananaBasket(candidate: FruitBasket<Fruits>): candidate is FruitBasket<Fruits.Banana> {
    return candidate.type === Fruits.Banana;
}
```

**UPDATE**

So it turns out that converting your existing code was not as easy as I thought, because extending from an enum doesn't work the same as a class or interface. Here is my updated example, with some interpretation. It's up to you if you want to use classes or plain javascript objects with types. I prefer classes if only for the ability to use `instanceof`.

This doesn't necessarily show you the adaptor pattern I mentioned (wrap your interface/class with another to make them have the same featureset), but it shows what would happen if you did (`FruitSlicer<T extends Fruit>`)

```
enum Fruits {
  Apple = "Apple",
  Banana = "Banana",
}

interface Fruit {
    fruitType: Fruits;
}

class Apple implements Fruit {
    public fruitType: Fruits = Fruits.Apple;
}
class Banana implements Fruit {
    public fruitType: Fruits = Fruits.Banana;
}

interface SlicedFruit {
    fruitType: Fruits;
    numberOfSlices: number;
}
interface FruitSlicer<T extends Fruit> {
    fruitType: Fruits;
    canHandleFruit(fruit: Fruit): boolean;
    slice(fruit: T): SlicedFruit;
}

class AppleSlicer implements FruitSlicer<Apple> { 
    public fruitType = Fruits.Apple;

    public canHandleFruit(fruit: Fruit): boolean {
        return fruit.fruitType === this.fruitType;
    }

    public slice(fruit: Apple): SlicedFruit{
        return {
            // if we turn the number of slices into a property,
            // we could make an abstract base class that does this work for us
            // for any future fruit.
            fruitType: fruit.fruitType,
            numberOfSlices: 8
        }
    }
}

class BananaSlicer implements FruitSlicer<Banana> { 
    public fruitType = Fruits.Banana;

    public canHandleFruit(fruit: Fruit): boolean {
        return fruit.fruitType === this.fruitType;
    }

    public slice(fruit: Banana): SlicedFruit {
        return {
            fruitType: Fruits.Banana,
            numberOfSlices: 15
        }
    }
}

const allSlicers: FruitSlicer<Fruit>[] = [ new AppleSlicer(), new BananaSlicer() ]

// in terms of objects, a basket can hold several types of fruit. We could make a basket of
// all bananas or all apples, but it doesn't make sense to have ONLY that option.
// this example has a full basket of any fruit type, and we decide for each fruit
//  what type of slicer to use later on.
const basket: Fruit[] = [ new Apple(), new Banana(), new Banana(), new Apple()];

basket.forEach(f => {
    // allSlicers.find could make use of the factory pattern, 
    //      and could be more performant with a map lookup, etc.
    const slicedResult: SlicedFruit | undefined = allSlicers.find(s => s.canHandleFruit(f))?.slice(f);
    console.log(!slicedResult ? 'null' : `${slicedResult?.fruitType} sliced ${ slicedResult.numberOfSlices } ways!`);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) function to check the type of basket before using the basket.

```
enum Fruits {
  Apple = "Apple",
  Banana = "Banana",
}

// These interfaces can have completely different shapes as shown.
interface AppleSlicer { apple(): void }
interface BananaSlicer { banana(): void }

export type FruitSlicer<TType> = TType extends typeof Fruits.Apple
  ? AppleSlicer
  : TType extends typeof Fruits.Banana
  ? BananaSlicer
  : never

export interface FruitBasket<TType extends Fruits> {
  type: TType
  slicer: FruitSlicer<TType>
}

function checkTypeOfBasket<T extends Fruits>(basket: FruitBasket<Fruits>, type: T): basket is FruitBasket<T> {
  return basket.type === type
}

const test = (basket: FruitBasket<Fruits>) => {
  if (checkTypeOfBasket(basket, Fruits.Apple)) {
    // after checking, typescript understands the basket is an apple basket
    basket.slicer.apple()
  }
}
```